# "Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 3 in..."

Tags: php, error-handling

I've searched other questions but can't find a workable solution. This is a CMS program, I've tried to upload files to any directory and am getting the following the error:

```
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 3 in /home/...on line 1017
```

Here is the code, any suggestions?:

```
function _IsValidPath($Path)
{ // First check if the path starts with the starting directory     
$basePath = preg_replace("/{1,}/", "/", $_SESSION['rootdirectory'] . '/' . // this line (1017) causing the error
 $_SESSION["startingdirectory"]);
$sdPos = strpos($basePath, $Path);
if (!is_numeric($sdPos))
        {
            $sdPos = strpos($Path, $basePath);
        }

        if(is_numeric($sdPos) && $sdPos == 0)
        {
            // Make sure it doesn't contain any invalid characters
            if(is_numeric(strpos($Path, "..")) ||
            (is_numeric(strpos($Path, "./"))) ||
            (is_numeric(strpos($Path, "//"))) ||
            (is_numeric(strpos($Path, "\\"))) ||
            (is_numeric(strpos($Path, "../"))) ||
            (is_numeric(strpos($Path, "&"))) ||
            (is_numeric(strpos($Path, "*"))) ||
            (is_numeric(strpos($Path, " "))) ||
            (is_numeric(strpos($Path, "'"))) ||
            (is_numeric(strpos($Path, "\?"))) ||
            (is_numeric(strpos($Path,"<"))) ||
            (is_numeric(strpos($Path, ">"))))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                // The path is OK
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to:

```
$basePath = preg_replace("@/{1,}/@", "/", $_SESSION['rootdirectory'] . '/' .
 $_SESSION["startingdirectory"]);
```

`preg_replace` expects the regular expression to be delimited by a character inside the string so that you can specify flags like `g` or `i` afterwards (I usually use `@`).  It was treating `/` as the delimiter.  See the [`preg_replace` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for more info.

Even still, this code **doesn't make much sense**, and there is probably a much better way to accomplish what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
/{1,}/
```

Looks like you're trying to match 1 or more of *nothing*.